# Method returns 0 instead of the number I assigned to the variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random

I'm trying to get the basics of iOS programming down. I have an app that shows a random number when I click a button.. At least, that's what I wanted to make. However, it doesn't seem to be working out.

I have the following basic method which should set the text of `myLabel` to the return value of `generateRandomNumber`. However, it always returns 0. I think the syntax I'm using here is correct since it works for the commented parts:

```
-(IBAction)myBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //[myLabel setText:@"test"];
    //[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g / 15", 3.14]];
    [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g / 15", [myModel generateRandomNumber]]];
}
```

The last line sets the label to display `0/15`. However, in my model, I have the following code ('static' for now):

```
-(double)generateRandomNumber
{
    randomNumber = 1.34;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

It doesn't return the 1.34 and I don't understand why it doesn't. Can someone clear this up?

*Update*
This is the code for my viewcontroller.m file:

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@implementation myViewController

    -(MyModel *)myModel
    {
        if (! myModel) {
            myModel = [[MyModel alloc] init];
        }

        return myModel;
    }


    -(IBAction)myBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g / 15", [myModel generateRandomNumber]]];
    }

    @end
```

Also, in the end, I want to make `generateRandomNumber` return a random number between 0 and 15. How would I do this? Would a simple line like:

`int x = arc4random() % 16;`

work for this? Or do I have to seed it in some way so it doesn't always return the same values when I run the application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any warnings (specifically, warnings about unrecognised selectors)?

Comment: JeremyP spotted the bug. It is highly recommended that you always start your instance variables with an underscore. That avoids this kind of bug and makes it visible when you access an instance variable instead of a property. Even when there's no bug, someone seeing that your code accesses an instance variable without underscore will always be unsure whether that is what you wanted to do, or whether it is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It doesn't return the 1.34 and I don't understand why it doesn't. Can someone clear this up?

Almost certainly, you haven't allocated and initialised the `myModel` object.  You can send messages to `nil` without crashing but the return value will be 0.

`arc4random()` doesn't need a seed.

**Edit**

Your init code looks OK but you are not calling int, in your `myBtnPressed:` method, you need

```
[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g / 15", [[self myModel] generateRandomNumber]]];
```

Comment: Updated my post with the initialisation of my myModel object.

Comment: It still looks the same to me.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I first had to send the `myModel` method to `self` so it would alloc/init the object and then run the `generate` method on the result of that; right? Easy to overlook that when you're just starting out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cabaret: that depends on the range you want.  On the assumption you want a `double` between 0 and 16, something like `(double)arc4random() / (UINT32_MAX / 16)` might work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you instantiating an object of your model type? I'm asking because you say that you have declared the function in `myModel.h` (Could be a typo).

And yes - to get a random number between 0 and X:

```
int rand = arc4random() % X;
```

And you don't need to seed the generator.

To return a double between 0 and 15:

```
// define this somewhere
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000

// and then use this
double val = floorf(((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * 15.0f);
```

[random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would I make it return a random `double` though? It only returns integers atm, but I would like to have numbers like.. 14.23, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever alloc/create the myModel object?

I'm guessing that you didn't, and you're just trying to use the class as a 'methods' class that doesn't store anything (I know there's a name for it, but I'm self taught so my terminology is pretty horrible!)

You *can* do this in objective-c, but you've got to use different syntax. Instead of using minus signs for the method declaration, use "+":

```
+(double)generateRandomNumber;
```

and now your method should be usable!